# Reduce Pickle size TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python-3.x, size, pickle, sklearn-pandas, tfidfvectorizer

I need to standar some parameters to build vectors based on text. That is why I am trying to pickle a TfidVectorizer from a group of text documents. Based on those parameters I need to vectorize new text documents and their features and weight criteria should be the same of the previous documents.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(
        strip_accents = 'ascii', sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2',
        encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words=spanish_stopwords,
        token_pattern = r'\w+[a-z,ñ]')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.Consumer_complaint_narrative).toarray()

features.shape
```

> (617, 22997)

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(tfidf, open("vectorizer3.pickle", "wb"))
```

vectorizer3.pickle size is 76.2MB. Is there a way to reduce this to 10MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using gzip

```
import gzip
import pickle

# writing into file. This will take long time
fp = gzip.open('tfidf.data','wb')
pickle.dump(tfidf,fp)
fp.close()

# read the file
fp = gzip.open('primes.data','rb') #This assumes that tfidf.data is already packed with gzip
tfidf = pickle.load(fp)
fp.close()
```

This method may not guarantee you in reducing the file size to < 10MB. But definitely, it will reduce the size of the pickle file